# How to extract section of log with sed, awk, grep if there is a match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to extract sections of log that match a particular string.

My log file consist of a series of HTTP traffic (request/response). For example:

```
[2016-11-11 06:52:07.452] [jettyserver-391] 201939 * Server has received a request on thread jettyserver-391
201939 > PUT http://localhost
201939 > Accept: application/json
201939 > Accept-Encoding: gzip
201939 > Content-Type: application/json
201939 > Host: localhost
201939 > Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{
  "att1": "WIFI",
  "att2": true,
  "att3": null,
  "country": "CANADA",
  "att5": null
}

[2016-11-11 06:52:07.555] [jettyserver-392] 201940 * Server has received a request on thread jettyserver-392
201940 > PUT http://localhost
201940 > Accept: application/json
201940 > Accept-Encoding: gzip
201940 > Content-Type: application/json
201940 > Host: localhost
201940 > Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{
  "att1": "ETHERNET",
  "att2": true,
  "att3": null,
  "country": "US",
  "att5": null
}

[2016-11-11 06:52:07.557] [jettyserver-391] 201940 * Server responded with a response on thread jettyserver-391
201939 < 200
201939 < Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id": 344134
}

[2016-11-11 06:52:07.557] [jettyserver-392] 201940 * Server responded with a response on thread jettyserver-392
201940 < 200
201940 < Content-Type: application/json
{
  "id": 344135
}
```

If I search for "ETHERNET", I'm expecting this output:

```
[2016-11-11 06:52:07.555] [jettyserver-392] 201940 * Server has received a request on thread jettyserver-392
201940 > PUT http://localhost
201940 > Accept: application/json
201940 > Accept-Encoding: gzip
201940 > Content-Type: application/json
201940 > Host: localhost
201940 > Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{
  "att1": "ETHERNET",
  "att2": true,
  "att3": null,
  "country": "US",
  "att5": null
}
```

Right now, I tried with `sed`, and I have semi-successful:

```
sed -n '/^\[/{x;/ETHERNET/{p;d}};/ETHERNET/H' test2
```

I have this output...

```
[2016-11-11 06:52:07.555] [jettyserver-392] 201940 * Server has received a request on thread jettyserver-392
  "att1": "ETHERNET",
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try `awk -v RS= '/ETHERNET/'` .. I think there is a duplicate

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks, this is the answer.

Comment: Do you REALLY want to match a regexp anywhere it can occur in the record (e.g. `/ETHERNET/`) or do you actually just want to match when specific fields have specific string values (e.g. `att1 == "ETHERNET"`)?

Answer (score 0):

if its known section (5 lines after-context(`-A5`), 8 line before-context(`-B8`)) you can use `grep` with `-A` and `-B` options, this should print 8 lines before and 5 lines after including matching lines:

```
$ grep -A5 -B8 'ETHER' test.file
[2016-11-11 06:52:07.555] [jettyserver-392] 201940 * Server has received a request on thread jettyserver-392
201940 > PUT http://localhost
201940 > Accept: application/json
201940 > Accept-Encoding: gzip
201940 > Content-Type: application/json
201940 > Host: localhost
201940 > Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{
  "att1": "ETHERNET",
  "att2": true,
  "att3": null,
  "country": "US",
  "att5": null
}
```